# Editar pergunta para adicionar detalhes informados através de comentário

Tags: debate, perguntas, edição, comentários

Geralmente alguns usuários adicionam poucos detalhes a sua pergunta, esquecem de colocar aquele trecho crucial para solução do problema e posteriormente através dos comentários que é identificado tal informação.

O que devemos fazer? Editar a pergunta e adicionar a informação que "faltava"?

Segue link de alguns exemplos:

[Somar números de uma coluna do MySQL utilizando PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/70294/somar-n%C3%BAmeros-de-uma-coluna-do-mysql-utilizando-php)
[Como centralizar uma árvore binária?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46308/como-centralizar-uma-%C3%A1rvore-bin%C3%A1ria)
[Ler uma SMS recebida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46163/ler-uma-sms-recebida)

Comment: Eu pessoalmente edito o título, mas o texto da pergunta geralmente evito descaracteriza-lo, a não ser que eu tenha copiado do comentário do autor, então neste caso adiciono na parte do corpo da pergunta que for mais conveniente, tentando remover o minimo possível. Sim eu sou a favor de editar, isto ajuda a melhorar as perguntas e mesmo que eu não saiba a resposta, eu sei que colaborei para outros usuários responderem :)

Comment: **Relatados:** http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1630/3635 , http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2441/3635 e http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2212/3635

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sim. Edite por favor!

Culturalmente falando, comentários são cidadãos de segunda classe em toda a rede da Stack Exchange, o foco aqui são perguntas e respostas, e quanto menos ruídos melhor.

Justamente por isso, comentários por muitas vezes estão sujeitos a remoção por parte da moderação sem aviso prévio, caso sejam considerados ruídos que não ajudam futuros visitantes. Se forem importantes são mantidos, se forem cruciais significa que estão no lugar errado e deveriam fazer parte de uma publicação (ou da pergunta, ou de uma resposta já existente ou de uma nova resposta, dependendo de quem comentou). Idealmente falando, é claro.

Eu quase fiz isso [nesse comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/70294/somar-n%C3%BAmeros-de-uma-coluna-do-mysql-utilizando-php#comment143968_70300) da sua resposta, só não o fiz por não saber se aquela informação tinha tanto valor assim, nesse caso acabei deixando um comentário para o AP para que ele incluísse na pergunta o que ele achasse relevante, visto que a pergunta dele gerou uma certa confusão e carece de maiores detalhes.

Para usuários que não possuem pontos de reputação o suficiente para aplicar uma edição sem passar pela fila de análise aconselho a deixar bem claro que o texto que você está inserindo na publicação na verdade é uma transposição de um comentário do autor, através do campo "Resumo da Edição", para não correr o risco de ser rejeitada.