# Seria uma má prática reeditar perguntas ja ultrapassada pelo tempo?

Tags: debate, comportamento, respostas, edições-sugeridas

Seria ou não aconselhável fazer certas "*correções*" em uma questão antiga para melhorá-la nos seguintes aspectos:

- atualiza-la
- corrigi-la
- dicas e sugestões feitas no [comentário](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3997/editar-pergunta-para-adicionar-detalhes-informados-atrav%c3%a9s-de-coment%c3%a1rio)
- implementar uma nova rotina(codigo fonte de resposta) melhorada
- inserir links de outras fontes do mesmo assunto
- acrescentar recursos relacionados tipo [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22726/como-esconder-mostrar-uma-div-em-html), uma única reposta com **três** *tecnologias* diferentes

.. entre outros *pequenos* detalhes a mais.

Me bateu esta dúvida ja algum tempo atrás, após revisar alguns de meus tópicos

Por que disso? posso explicar, vamos por parte.

Utilizei "screen shot" como exemplo, agora esta **fora do ar**

Alguns "erros grotescos de português" **cometidos** por mim

Dicas, feitas por parte dos colegas sobre **minha própria respostas**.

Ou até mesmo numa **resposta falha** dada por algum colega.

> Enfim tudo quanto parecer irregular ou fora de segmento da pergunta.

Comment: Sobre o screenshot, lembre de fazer upload pelo sistema do site, em vez de por link direto, assim fica uma cópia local. O resto, sempre que puder melhorar, melhore. O único cuidado é não descaracterizar a pergunta caso tenha respostas reais (tem resposta que é tão chute que é como se não existisse), para não invalidar nada que os colegas postaram. Quanto às respostas, é legal melhorar tudo que puder, mas de preferência não mudar o sentido ou solução de uma resposta muito bem votada ou aceita, em respeito aos votos dados, preferindo adicionar um complemento sem apagar o núcleo original.

Comment: @Bacco Obrigado por sua gentiliza em opinar e dar sua dica em especial porque desconhecia até então [...]fazer upload pelo sistema do site, em vez de por link direto[...] vou procurar saber mais.

Comment: Veja aqui que quando você manda um arquivo (ou mesmo um link) pelo sistema do site, ele importa no _imgur_: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3VbK.gif (note o endereço final inserido)

Comment: @Bacco Mais uma vez agradeço auto-ajuda. Jamais havia percebido isso logo no editor de perguntas, que vacilo meu.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

É sempre um bom momento para editar conteúdo que não está na sua melhor forma. Desde que melhore mesmo, não mude o sentido, não pareça outra coisa e principalmente que invalide respostas dadas (se for pergunta), editar é muito útil, não importa quando foi postado originalmente. Você pode editar o conteúdo de todos, mas é claro que deve ter especial cuidado se o conteúdo não é seu.

Comment: A intenção é essa mesmo [...]editar conteúdo que não está na sua melhor forma[...] mas sem mudar o sentido da mesma, seria apenas agregar valor. E somente pretendo arriscar em meus próprios tópicos, não costumo mexer nos demais colegas.

Answer (score 4):

Do meu ponto de vista;

Editar as perguntas só se for para:

- Corrigir textos
- Corrigir marcação
- melhorar o enunciado
- tornar o título mais intuitivo fazendo a pergunta ser encontrada por futuros visitantes
- tornar mais evidente a tecnologia usada, as vezes duas tecnologia podem ter o mesmo nome o que confunde os visitantes, então neste caso *inserir links* (como você disse é interessante)

Eu não entendi isso que você disse *implementar uma nova rotina melhorada* e isso *recursos relacionados*, eu só consigo presumir que você está confundindo PERGUNTAS e RESPOSTAS. Se a edição que se refere é editar qualquer postagem do site, então para RESPOSTAS a coisa é diferente, neste caso acho que é sim interessante editar, o mesmo que citei sobre perguntas e de resto tenha em mente o que o bigown falou, não mude o sentido, não altere a intenção do autor, se tem uma informação super-nova que muda algo o melhor talvez seja formular uma nova resposta.

Comment: Enquanto a "recursos relacionados" quero expressar-me a bibliotecas que esta ai para nos ajudar. Então seria uma resposta em Javascript Puro e outra em JQuery pra quem prefere. Apesar de não ter conhecimento profundo sobre elas.

Comment: Isso que estou a pergunta no "meta" são coisas que penso que poderia melhorar em meus próprios tópicos, nada além do mais.

Comment: Quando digo "implementar uma nova rotina melhorada" me refiro adicionar nova reposta de minha autoria, para futura pesquisa. Sem desmerecer a quem coube me responder. Claro que nesta altura ja defini o "Voto" para ele.

Comment: Mas é isso que eu disse @DiegoHenrique, note que no primeiro comentario vc falou biblioteca para ajudar e no terceiro vc disse, resposta de minha autoria, mas o titulo da sua pergunta é *"Seria uma má prática reeditar perguntas ja ultrapassada pelo tempo?"*, você dá a entender editar perguntas, o que não tem sentido com a sua proposta, já que tudo que parece que você disse se refere as perguntas, então respondi sobre o titulo "quando editar perguntas" e comentei e expliquei sobre "quando editar respostas" dizendo isso:

Comment: *o bigown falou, não mude o sentido, não altere a intenção do autor, se tem uma informação super-nova que muda algo o melhor talvez seja formular uma nova resposta.*, ou seja, me parece que vc está confundindo edição de resposta com edição de pergunta e ainda está confundindo levantar uma pergunta antiga com uma nova resposta com edições o que são todos situações diferentes, entende? Espero que eu tenha conseguido me expressar ;D

Comment: Me desculpe pela falta! [...]você dá a entender editar perguntas[...] Portanto declaro que não seria esse meu desejo  [...]levantar uma pergunta antiga[...] mas sim corrigir eventuais erros das palavras, isto é, todas as regras ortográficas da gramática portuguesa.

Comment: Quanto a _Respostas_ ja obtidas e votadas, quero deixar claro que não pretendo mudá-las mas agregar mas uma que achar necessário. Algumas das repostas dadas, percebi ao longo do tempo que as mesmas não roda perfeitamente em diferentes versões de navegadores modernos e obsoletos. E sempre procuro criar e fazer algo _Universal_, _Genérico_, _Padrão_. Basta olhar uma breve de meu "Perfil" no qual descrevo como sou e penso.

Comment: @DiegoHenrique mas você entendeu aonde foi a confusão do enunciado na sua duvida no META, né? é isso o qual estou tentando lhe orientar, existem situações para editar Perguntas e situações para editar Respostas, é isso ;)