# Porque essa edição foi rejeitada dizendo que muda o objetivo do AP?

Tags: suporte, edições-sugeridas, filas-de-análise

É errado incluir as informações de um comentário do AP na pergunta, quando ele não mais estiver cadastrado no site?

Faço essa pergunta pois tive uma [edição rejeitada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/146770) e as motivações para a rejeição foram:
"Esta edição descaracteriza o post para promover um produto ou serviço ou desfigura seu conteúdo."
e
"Esta edição altera o sentido ou propósito inicial do post. Mesmo edições substanciais devem procurar preservar os objetivos originais do autor."

No entanto, a edição foi justamente para incluir o propósito inicial do autor que está [num comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12871/como-lidar-com-depend%C3%AAncias-dlls-em-delphi-lazarus#comment22722_12871) e esclarecer a pergunta que só foi possível responder depois do comentário dele.

Acredito que estava seguindo as orientações já explanadas [aqui no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3998/2652) para incluir informações importantes que estão nos comentários dentro da pergunta, deixando os comentários desnecessários livres para serem removidos.

No entanto a rejeição me deixou em dúvida, não sei mais como proceder.

Comment: O que eu acho que a Rejeição foi utilizado a opção incorreta. Eu rejeitaria pela opção: `Esta edição não faz a publicação mais fácil de ser lida, mais fácil de ser encontrada, mais precisa ou mais acessível`. Faça a seguinte pergunta para si: "O que faz este trecho adicionado essencial para a pergunta?".  A pergunta já está completa com as informações que estão contidas nela. Mas vale lembrar que isso é MINHA opinião!

Comment: @Everson, eu editei para incluir a informação pois a pergunta fica ambígua sem ela. O AP fala de um recurso de um softwrare que outros podem não conhecer. E editei a ordem do texto para tornar mais claro o que o AP estava perguntando. Mas claro, se ninguém achar a informação importante, eu vou sinalizar os comentários como "não mais necessários" e seguir a vida. Eu estava esperando a aprovação para fazer isso.

Comment: Parece que realmente o que você tinha sugerido de edição foi o que o AP pôs no comentário. Talvez os revisores não analisaram o contexto completo ou talvez discordam dessa minha visão mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Eu defendo que o próprio AP deve incluir novas informações ou texto à pergunta. É complicado para os revisores aprovar uma edição onde é acrescentado novo texto, mesmo com a motivação sendo explicada.

Quando são corrigidos erros ortográficos, indentação (isso mesmo, a palavra correta é "[indentação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o)" e não "<s>identação</s>" como muitos usam) ou amostra de código (CTRL+k) ou problemas de visualização e ajustes no texto para que fique mais claro, é fácil de aprovar.

Aprovar inserção de texto ou alteração na redação da pergunta é arriscado ao revisor, pois caso aprove (ou não aprove!) fica sujeito à interpelação por parte dos usuários caso tenha feita a escolha errada (de aprovar ou rejeitar); ou pode ser interpelado pelos moderadores, ficando sujeito à algum tipo de punição(?).

Acho que, no caso específico desta pergunta, a edição foi desnecessária, mesmo o AP não sendo mais cadastrado no site, já que existem apenas 2 comentários na pergunta, sendo de fácil visualização. Ao contrário de que, se houvessem muitos comentários, essa edição poderia ser considerada boa, afim de que não fosse preciso *vasculhar* um monte de comentários para achar uma informação relevante à pergunta.

Acho que cada caso pode ser um caso particular, mas em regra, eu não costumo aprovar alterações de texto ou na redação de perguntas. É muito ruim você aprovar algo achando que está contribuindo para o bem e algum tempo depois receber uma mensagem de um moderador perguntando o motivo de você ter votado daquela forma.

Comment: *"Eu defendo que o próprio AP deve incluir novas informações ou texto à pergunta"* - não é essa a orientação do meta atualmente -> https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3998/2652

Comment: *"Aprovar inserção de texto ou alteração na redação da pergunta é arriscado ao revisor (...)"* - Mas se o revisor está em dúvida ou não tem o tempo necessário para fazer análise completa, ele pode simplesmente pular a revisão.

Comment: @EMBarbosa Mas se todo revisor pular, a edição não será aprovada, então, dá na mesma. Ou, quem quiser se arriscar a votar, fica sujeito a interpelações caso vote errado (achando que está votando certo). Em relação ao primeiro comentário, eu li o artigo citado, porém continuo achando o que escrevi. É uma recomendação (e não uma norma), porém um tanto complicada, ao meu ver, a não ser em casos específicos.

Comment: @EMBarbosa  Tanto que é raro aparecer edições com injeção de texto ou alteração na redação. Eu não quero me arriscar e vou rejeitar toda alteração assim (claro, eu leio o que foi feito, a motivação, entro na pergunta e passo o olho nos comentários, vejo a reputação do editor etc). Eu já pulei muitas edições quando fiquei na dúvida, normal, mas é preciso votar, o site funciona assim, no voto.

Comment: posso entender se você disser que a pergunta não precisa dos comentários. A interpretação é subjetiva e posso entender. Mas uma coisa é a edição não ser aprovada, outra é ser rejeitada. São duas coisas diferentes. Se a pessoa está em dúvida, o melhor é não votar. Eu acredito que isso vale pra todas as votações do site, não apenas pra análises. Deve-se votar conscientemente.